# F# treating internal module as private

Tags: .net, f#, module, visibility

Any ideas why the following doesn’t compile?

On the last line it tells me that Module1 is not defined.  If I remove the “internal” from Module1 it works fine.

I've got two code files and Module1.fs is above Module2.fs in the project.

Module1.fs

```
module internal Module1

let sample =
    5 + 4
```

Module2.fs

```
module Module2

let sample2 =
    3 + Module1.sample
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to give your modules a namespace so the `internal` module is visible to later ones.

```
let module internal MyNamespace.Module1
let module MyNamespace.Module2
```

Comment: For larger projects, I'd recommend omitting accessibility modifiers until the end, then adding signature files to take care of it.

Comment: It feels weird to me. Why we need another namespace to make `internal` functional?

Answer (score 5):

**Compiler bug**

While the answers here are workarounds, this behavior is still a compiler bug. Reading the docs and Don Syme's Expert F#, there is **no point that says** that types in internal modules will be accessible **only if you also use namespaces**.

Considering the code the compiler emits I would not see a difficulty to make types inside internal modules visible inside the assembly.

**Edit:**
Having filed this behavior to @fsbugs, the master himself, Don Syme, soon confirmed this being a bug. I added a workitem for this case:

https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/29

Comment: If you think this is a bug have you submitted a bug report either to fsbugs@microsoft.com or visualfsharp.codeplex.com?

Answer (score 2):

this should be a namespace problem.
Just add namespace definitions on top of both your files (the same namespace!) like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace

module internal Module1 =

let sample = 5+4
```

and

```
namespace MyNamespace

module Module2 =

let sample2 = 3 + Module1.sample
```

Comment: This doesn't compile as the module is then a local module, but the idea was right - Daniel's solution works.

Comment: NO - this did not compile because I forgot the "=" (as happens to me from time to time) - the solution is not *very* different from Daniels at all .... to be sure I just tested this *code* line to line ... and it surely is not some "local" problem - it works as expected. Of course you should insert some meaningfull namespace in there

Comment: The "=" sign is required as the module definition inside the namespace is a local module, which I don't particularly want to use - this is not a "local" problem but an F# language distinction, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233221.aspx

Comment: ok - your choice - may I ask why? The indentation? As I read your linked article it's allmost useless: "If you have multiple files in a project or in a single compilation, or if you are building a library, you must include a namespace declaration or module declaration at the top of the file"

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal either way, but it just seems simpler to use the top-level module declaration.  And yes, indenting the entire module would be a bit annoying.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW: funny fact: I didn't indent the definitions in my project (just like I posted) and it compiles and runs just find - but if you open the project again IntelliSense will show an error "possible incorrect indentation" - after compile the error will be gone again :)

Comment: @Carsten: Top-level namespace elements aren't required to be indented. As for module members, failing to indent them only generates a warning.